# pySerial 2.7, 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' : Import serial error in Python 3.5 (using Mac OSX 10.10 - Yosemite)

Tags: macos, arduino, python-import, pyserial, python-3.5

I have been trying to find a solution through the web, but none of the solutions I saw solved my problem. It will be very grateful for anyone that can solved my problem.

I have install the pySerial-2.7 module into the python using the tutorial below:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Interface-Python-and-Arduino-with-pySerial/

Everything went smoothly when I used Python 2.7 as I uninstall it and migrate to python 3.5

As I type this code:

> import serial

It shown me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "<_pyshell#0>", line 1, in <_module>
>      import serial
>    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/serial/**init**.py", line 21, in <_module>
>
> from serial.serialposix import *
>    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 58
>
> except IOError, e:
>                    ^
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The python 3.5 cannot import serial which i do not know how to solve. Any help for this error will be much appreciated.

Comment: I saw many references in webs that pySerial-2.7 can support the Python 3

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstall the pyserial using the Terminal in your MAC from extracting the tar file and running the installer again:

> `tar xfvz pyserial-2.7.tar.gz`
>
> `cd pyserial-2.7`
>
> `sudo python setup.py install`

If everything going smoothly. Then I tried to install for Python 3:

> `sudo python3 setup.py install`

A bit of searching revealed a bug ticket describing exactly this issue.

The solution is simple:

> `sudo rm -Rf build`
>
> `sudo python3 setup.py install`

When the next version of pyserial is released, this problem will be resolved. :-)